# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method Int32 CompareString

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to execute the query below. However I'm getting the exception message:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 CompareString(System.String, System.String, Boolean)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I've narrowed it down to specifically the line "Where hearing.JudgeName = judge" but I see no reason why this would not be translated. JudgeName and judge are both strings and I'm connecting to a sql server. What is going on here?

```
            Dim query = From hearing In Context.Hearings
                        From appeal In hearing.Appeals
                        From participation In appeal.Participations
                        Where Not appeal.SentDate.HasValue
                        Where appeal.StartDate <= pendingAsOfDate
                        Where hearing.JudgeName = judge
```

Even simplifying the query produces the same exception:

```
        Dim query = From hearing In Context.Hearings
                        Where hearing.JudgeName = "Test"



        Me.HasKey(Function(x) x.HearingId)
        Me.Property(Function(x) x.HearingId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
        Me.Property(Function(x) x.JudgeName).HasMaxLength(50)
```

Comment: Can you double check that both `JudgeName` and `judge` variable has the same data type? try casting (converting) `judge` as a string?

Comment: Yes, intellisense tells me both are strings, casting does not make a difference. I have another very similar project that does not have the same problem so this is blowing my mind.

Comment: Wait... you have multiple `From`s and `Where`s here, why not using `Join`s with `AndAlso` to combine them? Are those 3 tables have relationships with foreign keys? Probably the problem is not related with string comparison, but related with multiple `Where` conditions.

Comment: Can we get the model definitions (at least the fields used here/any keys between the classes)?

Comment: Has to be something VB specific, like `Option Compare Text`?

Comment: That line is not where the query happens.  Where are you actually executing the query?  Do you have a `foreach` loop that uses `query` for example?

Comment: Option compare is set to binary. Weirdly, if I run the query from my main app it works fine, but running it from the service layer project throws the exception so it must be something project specific too. Dim result = query.ToArray()

Comment: I deleted the project, started from scratch and moved my old source files. It is now working.